# Setting names to rows in DataGridView control?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, rows

VB.Net's DataGridView supports naming columns, but I was wondering if it could somehow do the same for rows, so that we could use something like this:

```
With DataGridView1
    .Rows.Add(4)

    .Rows(0).Name = "Setting1"
    .Rows(1).Name = "Setting2"

    'Added two columns at design time
    .Columns("Key").Row("Setting1") = "Key1"
    .Columns("Value").Row("Setting1") = "Value1"
    .Columns("Key").Row("Setting2") = "Key2"
    .Columns("Value").Row("Setting2") = "Value2"
End With
```

Do you confirm that it's not possible and we must use numeric indexes to refer to row numbers?

Comment: It must be an integer. Look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.item.aspx#Y0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Name` property on `DataGridViewRow`, so no, it's not possible.

You could always use a `Dictionary` to tie a name to a `DataGridViewRow`:

```
Dim dictRows As New Dictionary(Of String, DataGridViewRow)

'Map names to corresponding rows
dictRows.Add("Setting1", DataGridView1.Rows(0))
dictRows.Add("Setting2", DataGridView1.Rows(1))

'Access rows with names, using dictionary
dictRows("Setting1").Cells("Key").Value = "Key1"
dictRows("Setting1").Cells("Value").Value = "Value1"
```

Answer (score 0):

exist a way to do this using .Value

```
For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
Dim hashrow As String = hst("SQLServer")
Dim cellvalue As String = dr.Cells(hashrow).Value.ToString
                        values = values & "'" & cellvalue & "' , "
```

Comment: Could you explain your solution a bit more, please?

Comment: when you have a DataGridViewRow you can access to a single value using Cells property, just have to put the name of the column or the index of this,  like  dr.Cells('Column1').Value.ToString